# Convert MutbleArray to NSString in iphone SDKs

Tags: iphone

```
- (IBAction)doUpload:(id)sender
{

    NSMutableArray *selected_items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i<[appDelegate.notesArray count]; i++) {
        if (selected[i]) [selected_items addObject:[appDelegate.notesArray objectAtIndex:i]];


            UploadView *uploadview = (UploadView *)self.view;
            if (uploadview != nil)
            {

                [m_owner uploadString:here i want to pass the value];
                //[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            }


        }    
}
```

on my move code i want to pass the multiple values from UITableView to  [m_owner uploadString:here i want to pass the value];but i am only ble to pas the string to GDoc how to convert or split the mutbleArray to the Uplod string?
My DidSelecetRowAtIndexPathe code looks like this

```
 NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        selected[row] = NO;
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        selected[row] = YES;
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

Comment: I can't understand this. Please try to use a more proper English. Also, what is your goal with this, exactly? You'd like to concatenate the elements of an NSMutableArray into an NSString?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand very well what you want to do, but I think that you need the method to join the element of an array into a string, separated by commas or whatever you want.

```
NSString *uploadString = [[array valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

The method `description` of NSArray (as [documented here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)) returns a string that represents the contents of the array, formatted as a property list so it's useless for your purposes (in fact it inserts newlines and the outer parentheses).

Comment: It's only the case when the array itslef CAN be serialized into a property list, that is, all of its elements are valid property list objects (NSArray/NSDictionary, NSNstring, NSNumber, NSDate).